# How can I define a property that returns the current value of a RadioButton in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

The Code B is a customized `RecyclerView.Adapter` with `RadioButton`.

I hope to get the current selected index of the `RadioButton`, so I add a property `mySelectedIndex` in Code A, but `mySelectedIndex` will not change after it's called fro the first time.

How can I do this? Thanks!

And more,

```
private lateinit var selectedIndex= mCustomAdapter.getSelectedIndex() will not work too!
```

**Code A**

```
private lateinit var mCustomAdapter: CustomAdapter

private val mySelectedIndex by lazy {
        mCustomAdapter.getSelectedIndex()
}


private fun a(){
  backup(mySelectedIndex)
}


private fun b(){
  restore(mySelectedIndex) 
}
```

**Code B**

```
class CustomAdapter (val backupItemList: List<MSetting>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    val noRecord=-1
    private var mSelectedIndex = noRecord

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_recyclerview, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    fun getSelectedIndex():Int{
        return  mSelectedIndex
    }

    fun setSelectedIndex(index:Int){
        if (index in 0..(backupItemList.size-1) ){
            mSelectedIndex=index
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItems(backupItemList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return backupItemList.size
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bindItems(aMSetting: MSetting) {          

            itemView.radioButton.setOnClickListener {
                mSelectedIndex=adapterPosition
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            if(adapterPosition == 0 && mSelectedIndex == noRecord) {            
                itemView.radioButton.isChecked = true
                mSelectedIndex=adapterPosition
            }
            else {
                itemView.radioButton.isChecked =(adapterPosition == mSelectedIndex)
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `by lazy` delegation here you're making sure that the same value will be returned after the first initialization of `mySelectedIndex`.

You might want to omit the delegation and do something like this instead:

```
private val mySelectedIndex
    get () = mCustomAdapter.getSelectedIndex()
```

As a side note, this snippet above is not equal to the following:

```
private val mySelectedIndex
    get () = {
        mCustomAdapter.getSelectedIndex()
    }
```

The latter will return a function reference to `getSelectedIndex()` while the former will return its result.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
private val mySelectedIndex by lazy {
    mCustomAdapter.getSelectedIndex()
}
```

with

```
private val mySelectedIndex get () {
    return mCustomAdapter.getSelectedIndex()
}
```

or

```
private val mySelectedIndex get () =
    mCustomAdapter.getSelectedIndex()
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks! but I think that your code will cause error when you run the APP,  because that you don't initialize mCustomAdapter. You know that the definition in my code is `private lateinit var mCustomAdapter: CustomAdapter`

Comment: The only difference between `get() =` and `by lazy` is the former evaluates the lambda every time when accessed while the latter one evaluates the lambda only when first accessed. If `by lazy` doesn't cause error, `get() =` won't either. But if `by lazy` cause error, `get() =` will, too.

Comment: Thanks! I have test your code, the APP don't crash when I run it, but mySelectedIndex  don't return a correct Int value, it return a string of  the function

Comment: The string is Function0<java.lang.Integer>

Comment: Sorry, please remove the `=`. I've corrected my answer,

Comment: It's a personal mistake

Comment: Sorry, your latest code `private val mySelectedIndex get () { mCustomAdapter.getSelectedIndex()    }` doesn't work

Comment: What about now?