# Why can a val property be changed in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

The Code B is a customized RecyclerView apater with radio button.

mCustomAdapter is changed in both fun methodA() and fun methodB() in Code A, so the reference of `get () = mCustomAdapter.getSelectedIndex()` is changed too, and it means that the val property mySelectedIndex get value from different address.

In my mind, the val property can't be changed,  why doesn't the app cause error?

**Code A**

```
private lateinit var mCustomAdapter: CustomAdapter

private val mySelectedIndex get () = mCustomAdapter.getSelectedIndex()

private fun methodA(){
  mCustomAdapter= CustomAdapter(allListA)
  mRecyclerView.adapter= mCustomAdapter
  backup(mySelectedIndex)
}


private fun methodB(){
  mCustomAdapter= CustomAdapter(allListB)
  mRecyclerView.adapter= mCustomAdapter
  restore(mySelectedIndex) 
}
```

**Code B**

```
class CustomAdapter (val backupItemList: List<MSetting>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    val noRecord=-1
    private var mSelectedIndex = noRecord

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_recyclerview, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    fun getSelectedIndex():Int{
        return  mSelectedIndex
    }

    fun setSelectedIndex(index:Int){
        if (index in 0..(backupItemList.size-1) ){
            mSelectedIndex=index
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItems(backupItemList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return backupItemList.size
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bindItems(aMSetting: MSetting) {          

            itemView.radioButton.setOnClickListener {
                mSelectedIndex=adapterPosition
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            if(adapterPosition == 0 && mSelectedIndex == noRecord) {            
                itemView.radioButton.isChecked = true
                mSelectedIndex=adapterPosition
            }
            else {
                itemView.radioButton.isChecked =(adapterPosition == mSelectedIndex)
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**Modified**

I think the Code DD and Code EE can get the same effect, right?

**Code DD**

```
var aImpl = 0
val a: Int get() = aImpl

fun seta(){
    aImpl=5
}
```

**Code EE**

```
var b:Int=0

fun setb(){
    b=5
}
```

Comment: You should provide a minimal example.

Comment: Plaese have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50013573/how-can-i-define-a-property-that-returns-the-current-value-of-a-radiobutton-in-k

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In my mind, the val property can't be changed, why doesn't the app cause error?

You must adjust your intuition.

In Kotlin, `val` means "read-only property", not "immutable property". Only vals without a custom getter can be considered immutable.

Comment: I did not test it, but it may be possible to still change values of 'val' properties without custom getter by changing the backing field via reflection.

Comment: Thanks, does it mean that a val property can perform var property effect indirectly just like using 'ice1000''s  code?

Comment: @PaulGeorgPodlech You can do that with a Java `final` as well. We still consider `final` fields immutable in Java.

Comment: @HelloCW The equivalent of a `val` in Java is a `getX()` method. The method can do whatever it wants, even have side effects, and return whatever value it wants.

Comment: Thanks! please see my modified question

Comment: I don't see the point of your added text. Yes, the two snippets achieve a similar thing (and you can assure yourself without asking), but no, neither is an example of meaningful usage of these facilities.

Comment: Thanks!  In my mind that val property is thread-safe, but  it seems that it's not thread -safe  in Code DD, it 's just like var property in  Code DD,  any thread can change the variable  `aImpl`, different thread maybe get different value of 'val a' !

Comment: Kotlin's static checker takes this into account. You can smart-cast a nullable `val` into non-nullable only if it doesn't declare a custom getter.

Answer (score 1):

A `val` property can return different value every time you call it like this:

```
private var aImpl = 0
val a: Int get() = aImpl++
```

Since the return value of `mCustomAdapter.getSelectedIndex()` is changing, `mySelectedIndex` is obviously changing.

Comment: Thanks, does it mean that a val property can perform var property  effect  indirectly   just like using your code?

Comment: Yes. But if you don't have a custom `get`, you can still smart cast.

Comment: Thanks! In my mind that val property is thread-safe, but it seems that it's not thread -safe in Code DD, it 's just like var property in Code DD, any thread can change the variable `aImpl`, different thread maybe get different value of 'val a' !

Answer (score 1):

When regarding properties the keyword `val` means that there is no setter for that property, meaning you can't use the assignment operator `=` with it. It doesn't mean, that the returned value has to be constant over time.